# Limited languages choice on the creation of some type of node, not all

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I inherited a Drupal 7 installation where I have a problem on a new node creation: on some types of node the SELECT language choice is limited to 3 languages, on one type the SELECT is empty, while on every other node I can choose every language, *even not activated ones*.

Now, I took two node types, one with every language and one with the problem, and I checked on the Content Types properties ( /admin/structure/types ), but every option was the same.
Then I checked the configurations of every module that referred to languages, but I haven't found anything.

Every step was followed by a Cache Cleaning, but nothing changed.
So maybe it is because of a conflict or custom code, but I can't find anything looking for those node types or the languages in the code. In the meantime I also updated to the latest 7.

So, where do you think I should put my eyes on now? Thanks for your time.